# How to align item to parent frame grid in Figma?

Tags: figma

I have two frames which are nested inside each other. Parent frame has 12 column grid and I want child frame to have row grid for section spacing.

[image]

[image]

But when I'm placing element in child frame I can't align it to parent frame grid. It looks like element doesn't see it.

How to align items in child frame to grid from parent frame?

Comment: Objects snap to the layout grid of their parent. In your case the parent frame of this rectangle has no layout grid, so no snapping. I can totally see why you want to do it this way, but it's not exactly how Figma does it. This is just a guess, but I think you should make your frame 10 columns wide centered and if the objects inside the frame are 5 columns wide, you should add a 2 column layout grid to the frame. There are other articles about layout grids, but I think this says it pretty well: https://www.figma.com/blog/grid-systems-for-screen-design/#frames-within-frames

Comment: I wanted to have one column grid for all child frames so I don't need to recreate it for every child.

Comment: Try selecting child frame and then try align it by parent. Because the child elements in the child frame moving by their wrapper frame (which you call child but it's not)